# How to write a custom batched function in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, batch-processing

I am trying to create a custom pytorch layer that creates a gaussian heatmap of shape 16,3,224,224 for one video with 16 frames and size 3,224,224 . The function works however it cannot process batched data. For a batch of 10 videos, I am currently using a for loop to iterate over each video. This takes a lot of time and I want to process the videos in parallel. How can I make the function accept batched input like other pytorch models. Below is a simplified version of the for loop used.

I tried using torch operators as much as possible but I am still getting tensor dimension error due to the batched input.

```py
mask=torch.zeros((batch_size,16,3,224,224))
for i in range(batch_size):
  mask[i]=generate_heatmap(centers, sigma)
```

Comment: please add your existing implementation with the loop (or a short illustrative version of it)